# memory leak happened when use node spider and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I write a simple nodejs app (nodejs + express + mongoose), use node as spider to get some urls clear content and save it in mongodb. My vps is 256M memory, all the pages is less than 50.

When I access "/rss/init" then it will save 50 pages in mongodb. And then I access "/rss", it halt and the OOM happened.

And the code is less than 50 lines. Any idea?
all the code at https://github.com/atreeyang/web2rss/blob/master/routes/rss.js

```
router.get("/init", function(req, res) {
var urls = new Array("http-to-rss-url-1");
var rssItemArr = new Array();
async.each(urls, function (item, callback) {
    spide.fetchRss(item).then(function(a){
        for(var j in a){
            console.log("push ++" + a[j].link);
            rssItemArr.push(a[j]);
        };
        callback();
    });
}, function (err) {
    if(err) console.log("err1: " + err);
    else {
        var art = new article();
        async.each(rssItemArr, function (t, callback) {
            console.log("t ==" + t);
            spide.getCleanBody(t.link).then(function(b){
                art.link=t["link"];
                art.title=t["title"];
                art.content=b.content;
                art.save(function (err) {
                });
                callback();
            });
        }, function (err) {
            console.log("err2: " + err);
            rssItemArr = null;
        });
    }
});
res.render("index", { title: "init done" });
```

and the home page is pages' list

```
router.get("/", function(req, res, next) {

var q = article.find({},"link title",{limit:30})
q.exec(
    function (err, docs) {
        console.log("docs is ;;;==" + docs);
        res.render("index", { docs: docs });
    });
```

});

Comment: Because it is far "too simple" Replace the use of `async.each` with [`async.eachLimit`](https://github.com/caolan/async#each) as described in the documentation. Without that "limit", then you are just building up a potential "huge" list of concurrent operations, and why you are running out of memory. The "limit" parameter is a number representing the "maximum" concurrent processes to run under the loop.